# VLOOKUP can't return value more than once on a row

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm trying to pull a part# from one column based on the repair order # found in a range.  It works okay unless there is more than one repair order on that row.

On sheet2 in col A is a repair order #.  I need to search for that RO# on sheet1 in a range (H3:CO5000) where the ROs are listed horizontally in respect to their corresponding part#.  Once the function finds the RO# I want to return the part# which is in col D.

It works the first time it finds an RO# on that row, but the next time an RO# is to be found on that row, it returns #N/A.

Sheet 2

```
Col A | Col B | Col C |
RO#   | **Part#** |
```

Sheet 1 (called DEST MISMATCH)

```
Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D | ... |Col H | Col I | ... | Col CO |Part# 
data  | data | data | data | ... |RO#   | RO#   | ... | Last RO# | Part#
```

I want to look for and find ROs that may be on the same row as previous ROs that have been looked up and return the respective part #.

```
=VLOOKUP(A7,'DEST MISMATCH'!$H$3:$CO$5000,86,FALSE)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you simplify the scenario and explain the context of `the next time an RO# is to be found on that row, it returns #N/A.` What is the EXACT formula for "the next time"? As a new user here, please read this carefully: edit your question to add clarification. Then post a comment to alert the people who are following the question.

Comment: `I want to look for and find ROs that may be on the same row as previous ROs that have been looked up and return the respective part #.` -- If it's on the same row, isn't the part number the same??? You say the part# is in column D, but your Vlookup retrieves it from column CP.

Comment: #teylyn, on a sheet called DEST MISMATCH are rows that start with a part# on the left side, various other data in the columns moving to the right and then starting in column H begin RO numbers associated with that part.  Each unit/part has a distinct RO# like a SKU.  So part ABC could have 20 units with individual RO numbers.

Comment: When I try to pull the part#s based on the RO#s in a particular row, it only recognizes the first RO in the range I specify.  When it comes to an RO for another part# it sees it fine, but then if there's more than one RO for that 2nd part# it does the same thing and gives an #N/A.

Comment: OH!  I should clarify... I am trying to pull data from 'sheet 1' to another 'sheet 2'.

Comment: I wrote in my first comment: `As a new user here, please read this carefully: edit your question to add clarification. Then post a comment to alert the people who are following the question.` You don't seem to have understood that. We don't have chatty conversations in comments. Put EVERYTHING relevant to your question into your question. You can edit your question at any time. That way, people who read the question get all the information without having to weed through a page of comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you can try create new column on sheet1, and concatenate all the ROs. Quick way to concatenate the cells in range can be found in this link,
https://www.get-digital-help.com/2011/02/09/concatenate-a-cell-range-without-vba-in-excel/

Say you created the new column CM with the concatenate value. you can use the index and match with a wildcard in sheet2 as shown below.
=index($CO$3:$CO$5000,match("*"&A7&"*",$CM$3:$CM$5000,0))

Comment: Sheet 1 is called 'DEST MISMATCH' - so I put the following into my cell - =INDEX('DEST MISMATCH'!$CO$3:$CO$5000,MATCH(""&A5&"",'DEST MISMATCH'!$CM$3:$CM$5000,0)) .  I used TEXTJOIN to do the concatenate.  It works but only for the first RO on a row, the others come up as #N/A.

Comment: Perhaps the INDEX/MATCH isn't seeing the delimiter ','?

Comment: sorry when i posted the formula with asterisk it is just left as empty.  u need to put the asterisk front and back of A5=INDEX('DEST MISMATCH'!$CO$3:$CO$5000,MATCH("asterisk"&A5&"asterisk",'DEST MISMATCH'!$CM$3:$CM$5000,0))

Comment: SO CLOSE!!! :)  Only one little problem left...  It works as desired but if there's no RO# in A5 it seems to see that as a blank cell and then returns the part number for the first row which of course has blank cells in the range.

Comment: Then, add the if function. =if(A5<>"",=INDEX('DEST MISMATCH'!$CO$3:$CO$5000,MATCH("asterisk"&A5&"asterisk",'DEST MISMATCH'!$CM$3:$CM$5000,0)),"")

Comment: Tried this, =IF(A5<>"",INDEX('DEST MISMATCH'!$CO$3:$CO$5000,MATCH("asterisk"&A5&"asterisk",'DEST MISMATCH'!$CM$3:$CM$5000,0)),"") with same result.  I removed the '=' before INDEX because it was throwing errors.

Comment: May i know what is in A5? Alternatively, you can check if A5 is starting with RO. so meaning, =IF(Left(A5,2)="RO",INDEX('DEST MISMATCH'!$CO$3:$CO$5000,MATCH("asterisk"&A5&"asterisk",'DEST MISMATCH'!$CM$3:$CM$5000,0)),"")

Comment: The RO# has a syntax like this, OB3104A6  or TC130654.  There is no 'RO' preceding it.

Comment: If A5 is an empty cell the if(A5<>"",...,"") should work where it will return the value as "". You can use =Code(A5) where A5 is the empty cell to check what character is in there.

Comment: Otherwise, assuming the length of the RO# is the same and the data is clean. May be you can use =If(Len(A5)=8,...,""). or may be you can put a condition len(A5) > a certain number of characters.

Comment: YES!!!  :)  Here's what worked - =IF(LEN(A5)=8,INDEX('DEST MISMATCH'!$CO$3:$CO$5000,MATCH("*"&A5&"*",'DEST MISMATCH'!$CM$3:$CM$5000,0)),"")

Comment: Credit to @kevin hiew for working with me to find a solution.  5 Stars!  The formula that worked for me was, 
=IF(LEN(A5)=8,INDEX('DEST MISMATCH'!$CO$3:$CO$5000,MATCH(""&A5&"",'DEST MISMATCH'!$CM$3:$CM$5000,0)),"")  See the comments for context.  Essentially, I had to use an INDEX-MATCH formula wrapped inside of an IF statement to ignore blank cells.